# Haceruna consulta php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como hago una consulta que dependa de otra tabla mysql en php?, tengo el siguiente codigo lo que hace es que se despliega para elegir el colegio, lo que debe hacer es que una vez se elejia el colegio, me muestre la informacion de la tabla estudiantes ( cuyo estudiante tiene un idcolegio "idcol") como puedo aplicar un join para hacer la consulta y que me muestre los resultados en la misma pagina, se que estoy mal
, pero no logro entender donde estoy mal alguien seria tan amable de revisar mi codigo y ayudarme un poco.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css//estilo.css">
        <title>Listado</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="contenedor">
        <h1 id="titulo">Estudiantes</h1> <hr> 
        <form action="listado.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
                 <label for="idcol" class="col-2 col-form-label">Buscar :</label> 
              <div class="col-10">
                 <select id="eidcol" name="eidcol" required="required" class="custom-select">
                 <?php
                       include('conexion.php');
                       $sql="Select idcol, cnom from colegios;";
                       $res = $con->query($sql);
                       echo "Cant: ".$res->num_rows;
                       foreach($res as $datos)
                       echo "<option value='".$datos['idcol']."'>".$datos['cnom']."</option>";
                       $con->close(); 
    
                   ?>
                 </select>
              </div>
            </div> 
           <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="offset-2 col-10">
                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
         </div>
         
         <?php
    
         $eidcol=$_POST['eidcol'];
         echo "<table>
         <tr>
             <th>No</th>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Estudiante</th>
             <th>Dir</th>
             <th>Cel</th>
             <th>E-mail</th>
         </tr>
        </table>";
    
         include ("conexion.php");
    
         $sql="SELECT *from estudiantes inner join colegios on idcol=eidcol where eidcol=$eidcol )";
         $res= $con->query($sql);
    
         $i=1;
          foreach($res as $datos ){
            echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['enom']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['epal']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['edir']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['ecel']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['email']."</td>";
            $i++;
            
          }
          $con->close();
    
    
    
         ?>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Con respecto al sql, es suficiente hacer esto: `SELECT * from estudiantes where idcol=$eidcol)`. Para mostrar los datos en la misma página deberías utilizar ajax.

Comment: Aun no comienzo con ajax

Comment: Pues necesariamente necesitas javascript y ajax si quieres mostrar en la misma página. Aunque ajax no se si del todo, pero si te facilitaria mucho las cosas.

Comment: como se haria con js

Comment: y me sigue sin funcionar la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas incluir `conexion.php` solo una vez y no cerrar la conexión para que puedas realizar todas las consultas necesarias. Porque, como lo estás haciendo ahora, consultas colegios, cierras la conexión y ya no puedes consultar estudiantes porque:

a) Obtienes un error por incluir nuevamente el *script* de conexión, volviendo a declarar clases o funciones
b) Obtienes un error porque no hay conexión activa

Desde el inicio del *script* verifica si ya se seleccionó un colegio, te va a servir para marcarlo en el *select* y para hacer la búsqueda de estudiantes.

En caso de que no se haya seleccionado un colegio, no muestras la tabla de estudiantes.

```
<?php
// Incluye la conexión desde el inicio del script
include 'conexion.php';

// Verifica si hay un colegio seleccionado con asignación ternaria
// (condición) ? 'Valor si cumple condición' : 'Valor si no cumple condición'
$eidcol = (isset($_POST['edicol'])) ? $_POST['edicol'] : 0;

// Inicia HTML
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Todas las etiquetas que ya tienes -->
    <!-- solo las omití para no hacer tan larga la respuesta -->
        <form action="listado.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
                 <label for="idcol" class="col-2 col-form-label">Buscar :</label> 
              <div class="col-10">
                 <select id="eidcol" name="eidcol" required="required" class="custom-select">
                 <?php
                       $sql="Select idcol, cnom from colegios;";
                       $res = $con->query($sql);
                       foreach($res as $datos) {
                           // Es el colegio actual? debería aparecer seleccionado
                           $sel = ($eidcol == $datos['idcol']) ? ' selected' : '';
                           echo "<option value=\"{$datos['idcol']}\"$sel>{$datos['cnom']}</option>";
                       }
                       // $con->close(); // <-- ¡No cierres la conexión!
                   ?>
                 </select>
   <!-- Más etiquetas, hasta llegar a donde tienes que mostrar los estudiantes -->

<?php
    // Solo si hay un colegio seleccionado previamente
    if($eidcol != 0) {
        echo "<table>
         <tr>
             <th>No</th>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Estudiante</th>
             <th>Dir</th>
             <th>Cel</th>
             <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>";
    
        $sql="SELECT *from estudiantes inner join colegios on idcol=eidcol where eidcol=$eidcol )";
        $res = $con->query($sql);
    
        $i=1;
         foreach($res as $datos ){
            echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['enom']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['epal']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['edir']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['ecel']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$datos['email']."</td></tr>";
            $i++;
            
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```